Vertical alignment in connecting arrow in tikzcd diagram
I want to make the following diagram with tikzcd in the best way. The \leadsto needs to centered vertically. I have two solutions, but don't like them and suspect there are better ways.

My current solution:
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=25pt]
A \ar{r}{f} \ar{d}[swap]{e} & B \ar{d}{g} \\
C \ar{r}[swap]{h} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\leadsto$}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=25pt]
F(A) \ar{r}{F(f)} \ar{d}[swap]{F(e)} & F(B) \ar{d}{F(g)} \\
F(C) \ar{r}[swap]{F(h)} & F(D)
\end{tikzcd}\]

I don't like this vertical shift:
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\leadsto$}
This is hack. For other diagrams (there are several of this type) I need to tweak this value. This is how it looks when we don't do this shift:

This doesn't look good.
What I did before is the following, which looks similar to the goal.
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=25pt]
A \ar{r}{f} \ar{d}[swap]{e} & B \ar{d}{g} \ar[phantom]{drr}{\leadsto} && F(A) \ar{r}{F(f)} \ar{d}[swap]{F(e)} & F(B) \ar{d}{F(g)} \\
C \ar{r}[swap]{h} & D & & F(C) \ar{r}[swap]{F(h)} & F(D)
\end{tikzcd}\]

Basically, I make one diagram for two, and hence can place the \leadsto arrow as a label for a phantom arrow. But this is also hacky, and it is not nice to maintain each diagram individually (maybe I am exaggerating here a bit, coming from software development... but this is just not cohesive).
What is the best way? I am not looking for tikzpicture solutions, by the way, only tikzcd.

No “magic value”:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ctikzcd}{O{}b}
 {% #1 = options for tikzcd
  % #2 = body of the environment
  %
  % save the body in a scratch token list
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  % replace all occurrences of & with \&
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \& }
  % typeset inside gathered using the modified token list
  \begin{gathered}
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand~replacement=\&,#1]
  \l_tmpa_tl
  \end{tikzcd}
  \end{gathered}
 }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{ctikzcd}[sep=25pt]
A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"e"'] & B \arrow[d,"g"] \\
C \arrow[r,"h"'] & D
\end{ctikzcd}
\quad
\leadsto
\quad
\begin{ctikzcd}[sep=25pt]
F(A) \arrow[r,"F(f)"] \arrow[d,"F(e)"'] & F(B) \arrow[d,"F(g)"] \\
F(C) \arrow[r,"F(h)"'] & F(D)
\end{ctikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

With gathered we can fix the baseline, that tikz-cd can't set properly. The small complication would be that diagrams passed to gathered need ampersand replacement, but we can do the substitution transparently.
See texdoc usrguide for information about \NewDocumentEnvironment.


Thank you! This is quite advanced for me. Can you please explain a bit (maybe by adding comments) what is happening in the definition of the environment? It is not clear to me.

@MartinBrandenburg I added some comments to the code

Thanks a lot! It is clearer now. Is it maybe also possible for you to explain a solution without the custom environment? I think you only did this to avoid code duplication? If so, it would be instructive to see this duplicated code nevertheless since I suspect that it is a bit easier to understand and also motivates your solution better. Not sure if it's possible, but it would be nice.

@MartinBrandenburg You need a “nonstandard” tikzcd environment, so a new one is the best option.

Like this:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=30pt,
                   labels = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt},
                   baseline=-2pt
                   ]
A \rar["f"] \dar["e" '] &   B \dar["g"]     \\
C \rar["h" '] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
$\leadsto$
\quad
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=30pt,
                   labels = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt},
                   baseline=-1pt
                   ]
F(A) \rar["F(f)"] \dar["F(e)" ']    & F(B) \dar["F(g)"] \\
F(C) \rar["F(h)" ']                 & F(D)
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}


Thank you, but shifting both diagrams is equally bad (maybe even more) as shifting the arrow. Also, I want to avoid magical values (1pt, 2pt) as mentioned. This is not what I am asking for.

@MartinBrandenburg No please any downvotes. . It is fine. There is much of effort. I was working on for 1h 30'.
